# Can't add System.Web.Extensions.dll to References

Tags: c#-4.0, dll, include

I can't 'System.Web.Extensions.dll' to my References. It is not in the .NET Reference List, so I had to browse to it in:

```
C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0
```

But even after that a small error icon is displayed in the library name.

I am trying to use

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
```

to serialize/deserialize JSON for my application.

What is the problem and how can I fix it ... ?

Comment: Is your project targeting version 4.0 of the .NET framework?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're targeting the Client Profile, which doesn't include the Web assemblies. Go into Project > Properties > Application and change Target Framework to ".NET Framework 4".

Also refer to this link. Its a good read
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharplanguage/thread/0710131c-2b7a-4531-bc34-7cceab44d93e